# Good reference for Linux scripting syntax? (If then while loop syntax)

Tags: linux

I'm new to linux scripting and i'm find the syntax a bit tricky to work with.

Does anyone no a good reference which describes the way in which linux commands should be written, is there some sort of linux scripting specification out there?

I'm trying to get this working:

```
from=$1
to=$2

rm SelectedSummedDatFiles
mkdir SelectedSummedDatFiles

ls *summed.dat > allSummedDatFiles


while read summedDatFile

    do  
    echo $summedDatFile
    number=`echo $summedDatFile | grep -o "[0-9]\{6\}"` 

    if [ $number -le $to ] && [ $number -ge $from ]
    then cp $summedDatFile SelectedSummedDatFiles/$summedDatFile
    fi  

done < allSummedDatFiles
```

Comment: Take a look at `man bash` (assuming `bash` is the shell you're using).

Comment: usually "man bash" or "man sh" is a good starting point. However I suggest you to take a look at http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ it's a pretty good and simple tutorial about shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to the Bourne-Again Shell, the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) is very comprehensive, complete and up to date. I would recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
from=$1
to=$2

# rm SelectedSummedDatFiles # should this be a rmdir?
mkdir SelectedSummedDatFiles

for summedDatFile ind *summed.dat; do
    echo "$summedDatFile"
    number=`echo "$summedDatFile" | grep -o "[0-9]\{6\}"` 

    if [ "$number" -le "$to" ] && [ "$number" -ge "$from" ]; then
        cp "$summedDatFile" SelectedSummedDatFiles/"$summedDatFile"
    fi
done
```

But I don't see in which way it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples here which may be a good reference of bash loops

- [Keeping You in the Loop – Bash For, While, Until Loop Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-for-while-until-loop-examples/)
- [12 Bash For Loop Examples for Your Linux Shell Scripting](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/bash-for-loop-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **bash** you can do

```
$ help if
$ help while
```

or just

```
$ help
```

to get the full syntax